# Google colab Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am tuning hyperparameters for a neural network via gridsearch on google colab. I got a "transport endpoint is not connected" error after my code executed for 3 4 hours. I found out that this is because google colab doesn't want people to use the platform for a long time period(not quite sure though).

However, funnily, after the exception was thrown when I reopened the browser, the cell was still running. I am not sure what happens to the process once this exception is thrown.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google colab, you can use their GPU service for upto 12 hours, after that it will halt your execution, if you ran it for 3-4 hours, it will just stop displaying Data continuously on your browser window(if left Idle), and refreshing the window will restore that connection.

In case you ran it for 34 hours, then it will definitely be terminated(Hyphens matter), this is apparently done to discourage people from mining cryptocurrency on their platform, in case you have to run your training for more than 12 hours, all you need to do is enable checkpoints on your google drive, and then you can restart the training, once a session is terminated, if you are good enough with the requests library in python, you can automate it.